# How do I correctly model the metadata for an entity with an array of entities?

Tags: breeze

I have a JSON that looks like this:

```
{
 username: 'johnDoe',
 password: 'mypassword'
 answers: [
  {
    field: '1',
    value: 'field1 value'        
   },
   {
    field: '2',
    value: 'field2 value'
   }
 ]
}
```

I'm trying to make an entity for it. I have gone with this entity:

```
function addUser() {
            addType({
                name: 'User',
                dataProperties: {
                    "id": {nullOk: true, isPartOfKey: true},
                    username: {max: 255, nullOk: true},
                    password: {max: 255, nullOk: false}
                },
                navigationProperties: {
                    answers: {
                        entityTypeName: 'Answer',
                        hasMany: true
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        function addAnswer() {
            addType({
                name: 'Answer',
                dataProperties: {
                    field: {type: INT, isPartOfKey: true},
                    value: {max: 255, nullOk: true}
                }
            });
        }
```

The problem is, whenever I do a `manager.saveChanges()` breeze strips away the array of `answers` from the json, so only username and password gets passed to my POST request.. why is that? I want to pass the entire object including the array of answers. What values should I alter to make it pass?

Comment: Can you give the Answer a `userId` property, so it can point to the User it belongs to?

Answer (score 0):

You have several modeling problems:

- no key for `User`
- no foreign key linking `Answer` to `User`
- strong probability that `Answer` is not really an `EntityType`

An entity must have a **non-nullable key** with unique values.

What is the true non-nullable key for your `User` type?  It can't be `id` because there is no "id" data in the JSON. How can the `userName` be nullable ... and the `password` not nullable?

As @SteveSchmitt observes, you don't see `Answer` instances in your `User.answers` because there is no foreign key (such as `userId` relating an `Answer` to `User`.

While the `Answer` entity type does have a non-nullable key, `field`, that is a strange name for a key. Is it unique across **all `Answer` instances** or just among the `Answer` objects within a given `User`?

I'm suspecting that `Answer` is not really an entity type. I'm suspecting also that the `Answer` data actually sit within the `User` data and are not stored in a separate database structure. If I'm correct, you probably want to model `Answer` as a [`Complex Type`](http://breeze.github.io/doc-js/complex-properties.html) and `User.answers` as an array of such types.

Come back with some answers to my questions and we'll see where this lead us.

Thanks for giving Breeze a try.